# I'm trying to use twine upload but it doesn't work, I'm pretty sure my password and username is correct

Tags: python, pypi, twine

the warning said

```
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details
```

here is what verbose said

```
INFO     Response from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/:
         403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://test.pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more
         information.
INFO     
         
           403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://test.pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for     
         more information.
      
          
           403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://test.pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more   
         information.
           Access was denied to this resource.<br/><br/>
         Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See
```

I don't know why my access was denied, I looked up some tutorial on youtube and did the same thing but they did not work

Comment: Add your code to see exactly what you've done.

Comment: @Сергей The code is in the title. It's `twine upload`

Comment: You're uploading to `test.pypi.org`. Are you sure you don't use login/password from `pypi.org`? They have different authentications. Do you have `username`/`password` in your `~/.pypirc`?